# Choose between robust Pooled OLS and robust Random effects

Tags: random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, robust

Please, can anyone tell me how can i choose between **Robust Pooled OLS** and **Robust Random effects**? Is there any command for robust estimation of Breusch-Pagan LM test or something else? To be more precisely, is there any command such as xtoverid, which we use when we make a decision between robust random and robust fixed effects?

Comment: In what sense is the word "robust" being used here?

Comment: Also see my answer to an older, but seemingly related question (without an upvoted answer) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111488/unbalanced-panel-pooled-ols-vs-fe-vs-re-which-method-yield-unbiased-and-robus?rq=1).